# Sending message on Intercom on user's behalf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intercom.js

does anyone know how to send a message from intercom(https://www.intercom.com/) on user's behalf? I need to set up an event listener that opens intercom chat window and sends a message when a some button is clicked.

i am working with react version of intercom if it helps.

will be very grateful for any hints.

Comment: Please share some code showing your efforts so far so people can actually help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for those who are in the same trouble:

https://developers.intercom.com/reference#user-or-contact-initiated-conversation

Comment: Url is not working anymore.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the Intercom chat widget, you can pre-populate a custom message in the widget on the user's behalf like so

```
const myCustomMessage = 'Hi there!'

window.Intercom('showNewMessage', myCustomMessage)
```

Of course, the user still has to actually send the message. This might not be exactly what you wanted but it's an alternative in case you want to fully automate everything *except* the decision to send the message (which is the right UX in a lot of situations).

[Documentation is here.](https://developers.intercom.com/docs/intercom-javascript#section-intercomshownewmessage)

Answer (score 1):

For sending messages on the user's behalf, you may check this out https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference/create-a-conversation

You may need the user's `user_id` or `id` from the reference above to create a conversation. For those who are using MobileSDK or [intercom_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/intercom_flutter/install), the `id` is not provided within the package or SDK. I found a workaround by using this [Search for contacts API](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference/search-for-contacts#accepted-fields) to get the `id`.